# Is there any app to clear cache on iOS?

Tags: iphone, applications

I've read that applications on iPhone create some service files that even after its removal still on your device. To clean up iPhone it's recommended to delete apps and then install them again. 
Is there any program that allows clearing cache without deleting apps?

Answer (score 1):

Try [PhoneClean](https://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/) make sure you don't let it clear your music album covers. It gives different options to clear up space. Personally, I clean my stuff out myself using software such as [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) and [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com). Choice is yours. [PhoneClean](https://www.imobie.com/phoneclean/) for simplicity, [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) for advanced features.